# Why aren't my scripts (that are correctly linked) not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My custom JQuery file as well as Masonry Jquery are linked but not working.You can see that it links correctly in the source file: view-source:http://michellecantin.ca/test/features/notification-boxes/

JQuery is also linked and I'm pretty sure it is working.

Why aren't my scripts working?

ps: I use it in a wordpress theme.

Comment: **ALWAYS** check js error console before you ask a question

Comment: Also note links only questions are not always welcomed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your page, look at your browser console it says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

in the file http://michellecantin.ca/test/wp-content/themes/neon_lights/js/jquery.js?ver=3.7.1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 120
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            // window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
//<-- extra }) here

$(document).ready(function () {

    var $container = $('.masonry-container');
    // $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        isAnimated: true // <-- extra , here 
    });
    // });

});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.toggle-view-style1 li, .toggle-view-style2 li, .toggle-view-style3 li, .toggle-view-style4 li, .toggle-view-style5 li')
        .click(function () {
        var text = $(this).children('div.panel');
        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
        }

    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.close-alert-box-style1, .close-alert-box-style2, .close-alert-box-style3, .close-alert-box-style4')
        .click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        // Although I recommend just hiding it
        // like this
        // $(this).parent().hide();
        // or fade it out
        // $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabs li').click(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var allPanels = jQuery('.accordion > dd').hide();
    jQuery('.accordion > dt > a').click(function () {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        if (jQuery(this).parent().next().is(':hidden')) {
            jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').fadeIn();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-content').fadeIn();
});

$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect: "fadeIn",
    container: $("#content")
});
```

Comment: Was just getting ready to post this. This is a great example of how proper indentation can help you see errors more clearly. Good find!

Comment: I didn't know the browser console existed! This is going to make my life much easier! Thank you!

Comment: @MichelleCantin also always use a proper indentation scheme and use a proper IDE for development so that silly mistakes like this will get highlighted during the coding phase itself

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't understand why I would add an extra }). When I do that in my code editor, it says its a syntax error.

Comment: @MichelleCantin it can happen a lot of times... but following simple rules like indentation could help to fix it

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added it with the proper indentation and it said its a syntax error. My JavaScript isn't working with or without.

Comment: @MichelleCantin did you put the updated file in the test page you provided... there I can still see the syntax error... also make sure to clear your browser cache or sometimes the script file might be cached